# Error reading webpack-stats.json

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, npm, webpack

I know this is probably a long shot but I have been desperately attempting to launch a `Django` application from the `Animal Disease Spread Model` simulator located here: https://github.com/NAVADMC/ADSM.

I have made a `docker` file to try to replicate the environment and I have even pushed the image to `docker hub`.

```
docker run --name adsm-app -p 8000:8000 -d mgahan/adsm:latest
open http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following error when I navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:8000`:

[image]

Any tips to what might be going wrong and possible fixes?

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD ADSM ADSM
RUN pip install -r ./ADSM/Requirements-Nix.txt
RUN pip install -r ./ADSM/Requirements.txt
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ADSM

# Install node
# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 7.0.0

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Are you running `npm start` anywhere ?

Comment: I just `docker exec -it`'d into the container and tried running `npm start` and I am still having troubles, although this could be my issue

Comment: hmmm. I wonder if you need to provide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 to node or something. I have a boilerplate repo for django/webpack loader that might be helpful to look at https://github.com/denvaar/drf-react-boilerplate